# Creating an address book using C with structures

Tags: c

My intent was to create an address book containing 10 contacts using C's structures. The user must insert the contacts one by one and my program should print the entire address book. The compilation is successful but when I run my program, it prints only the first contact and then I get segmentation fault. This is my code:

File Ex7.h:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define DIM 10

struct person {
    char name[40];
    char surname[40];
    char date[11];
    char number[11];
};

typedef struct person Person;

void dataEntry(Person *person);
void printPerson(Person person);
void printAddressBook(Person *addbook[10]);
```

file Ex7.c:

```
#include "ex7.h"

void dataEntry(Person *person) {
    printf("Insert name: ");
    gets(person -> name);
    printf("Insert surname: ");
    gets(person -> surname);
    printf("Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: ");
    gets(person -> date);
    printf("Insert phone number: ");
    gets(person -> number);
}



void printPerson(Person person) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", person.name);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", person.surname);
    printf("Date of birth: %s\n", person.date);
    printf("Number: %s\n\n", person.number);
}



void printAddressBook(Person *addbook[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printPerson(*addbook[i]);
    }
}
```

file main.c:

```
#include "ex7.h"

int main(void) {
    Person* addbook = (Person*) malloc(DIM*sizeof(Person));
    printf("DATA ENTRY\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printf("Person %d:\n", i);
        dataEntry(&addbook[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nPRINTING ADDRESS BOOK...\n\n");
    printAddressBook(&addbook);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled everything typing: gcc -o main main.c ex7.c -std=c99

Comment: `Person* addbook = (Person*) malloc(DIM*sizeof(Person));` : `addbook` is pointer to 10 Person. `Person *addbook[10]` : `addbook` is array of 10 pointer to Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this part:

```
void printAddressBook(Person *addbook[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printPerson(*addbook[i]);
    }
}
```

the method expects an array of person pointers where in main you are passing a pointer to the persons array, not the persons array you allocated.
So change the method into:

```
void printAddressBook(Person *addbook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printPerson(addbook[i]);
    }
}
```

And in main call it this way:

```
printAddressBook(addbook);
```

Answer (score 0):

First **do NOT use gets**. It is deprecated and no longer part of the current standard. `fgets` works fine. You must be consistent in how you are passing a pointer to your collection of structs to each of your functions. Additionally using malloc in this way will cause complaints by `valgrind` of `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. You can allocate with `calloc` to insure all data is initialized to `NULL`. One way of correcting these problems is as follows. A new input routine is provided using `getline` to obtain input instead of 'gets':

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define DIM 10

struct person {
    char name[40];
    char surname[40];
    char date[11];
    char number[11];
};

typedef struct person Person;

void dataEntry(Person *person);
void printPerson(Person *person);
void printAddressBook(Person *addbook);

int main(void) {
    Person* addbook = calloc (DIM, sizeof(Person)); /* calloc initializes all storage */
    printf("DATA ENTRY\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printf("Person %d:\n", i);
        dataEntry(&addbook[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nPRINTING ADDRESS BOOK...\n\n");
    printAddressBook(addbook);
    if (addbook) free (addbook);
    return 0;
}

/* get string input using getline and write to 'string' */
void getinput (char *string)
{
    ssize_t read = 0;                   /* values to use with getline       */
    char *line = NULL;                  /* forces getline to allocate mem   */
    size_t n = 0;                       /* bytes to read, 0 no-limit        */
    read = getline (&line, &n, stdin);  /* read from stdin with getline     */
    if (line[read - 1] == '\n')         /* if newline at end of line        */
        { line[read - 1] = 0; read--; } /* strip newline                    */
    strncpy (string, line, read);       /* copy line w/o linefeed to string */
    if (line) free (line);              /* free memory allocated by getline */
}

void dataEntry(Person *person) {
    printf("Insert name: ");
    getinput (person -> name);
    printf("Insert surname: ");
    getinput (person -> surname);
    printf("Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: ");
    getinput (person -> date);
    printf("Insert phone number: ");
    getinput (person -> number);
}

void printPerson(Person *person) {
    printf("Name    : %s\n", person -> name);
    printf("Surname : %s\n", person -> surname);
    printf("D.O.B.  : %s\n", person -> date);
    printf("Number  : %s\n\n", person -> number);
}

void printAddressBook(Person *addbook) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printPerson(&addbook[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to free the memory allocated at the end.

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/abook
DATA ENTRY

Person 0:
Insert name: dog
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 12/12/1912
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 1:
Insert name: cat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 11/11/1911
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 2:
Insert name: rat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 10/10/1910
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 3:
Insert name: flat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 09/09/1909
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 4:
Insert name: fat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 08/08/1908
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 5:
Insert name: bat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 07/07/1907
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 6:
Insert name: hat
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 06/06/1906
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 7:
Insert name: Matt
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 05/05/1905
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 8:
Insert name: george
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 04/04/1904
Insert phone number: 555-1212
Person 9:
Insert name: harry
Insert surname: fish
Insert date of birth [mm/dd/yyyy]: 03/03/1903
Insert phone number: 555-1212


PRINTING ADDRESS BOOK...

Name: dog
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 12/12/1912
Number: 555-1212

Name: cat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 11/11/1911
Number: 555-1212

Name: rat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 10/10/1910
Number: 555-1212

Name: flat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 09/09/1909
Number: 555-1212

Name: fat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 08/08/1908
Number: 555-1212

Name: bat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 07/07/1907
Number: 555-1212

Name: hat
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 06/06/1906
Number: 555-1212

Name: Matt
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 05/05/1905
Number: 555-1212

Name: george
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 04/04/1904
Number: 555-1212

Name: harry
Surname: fish
Date of birth: 03/03/1903
Number: 555-1212
```